# Why isAlive() method of Thread is declared native?

Tags: java, multithreading

Why `isAlive()` method has been declared native in Thread.java? Which class implements this? I know native methods are implemented outside Java. The class which implement this is loaded by loading the respective library. But I am curious to know which class implements `isAlive()` method? And why it is declared native?

Comment: Threads are part of the operating systems and implemented in reality by the operating system (assuming you have native threads)

Thus when you want to access this underlying resource, a native call needs to be made.

Comment: I would way it's because JVM does not implement it's own scheduler and it uses native OS threads. So this method is just a wrapper around some OS kernel syscall.

Comment: Voted to reopen because this is *not an exact duplicate*, this is a *specific* question which can be answered *reasonably* .

Comment: "The classes which implement these are loaded by loading the respective libraries. But I was curious to know which class implements isAlive() method?" Native methods do not need to be implemented by classes. They are implemented _natively_ - usually in C or C++. What are you actually asking?

Comment: Your question embodies not one but two contradictions in terms. If it's native, it isn't implemented by a class at all. And if it's implemented 'outside Java', it isn't implemented in a Java class.

Comment: I don't want to override it anyway. I am just curious to know where is it's implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why isAlive() method has been declared native in Thread.java?

Possibly because it *has to be* implemented in native code.  Possibly because it can be implemented *more simply* in native code. Possibly for historical reasons; i.e. it was declared to be `native` a *long time ago*, and it has been left that way to minimize potential disruption cause by "fixing" it.

You might get more insight by looking at the C++ source code for native code methods for `Thread`, across all platforms.  But obviously the source code of historical implementations is not available.

> Which class implements this?

None.  It is `native`.

> I know native methods are implemented outside Java. The class which implement this is loaded by loading the respective library.

Obviously it is not a Java class then ...

But actually, the library is probably linked into the core `java` executable rather than being dynamically loaded.

> But I am curious to know which class implements isAlive() method?

Ermm ... are you talking about a C++ class?  It will be platform dependent.  A lot of the native classes have different versions in the code base for Windows, Linux and Solaris (and possibly Mac now, I guess).

If you are really curious, I suggest you checkout the code from the OpenJDK Mercurial repos, or download the source bundles, and search.  Unfortunately, the OpenJDK project doesn't provide a nice convenient web-based source code browser for the repository.  (So even if I found it for you, I couldn't give you a stable link to it.)

> And why it is declared native?

You are repeating yourself.  (But Java classes aren't declared `native`.  Java methods are ...)

Comment: Yes I was talking about a C++ class or any program which provides its implementation. But thanks anyway for good wrap up.

Comment: @ParagJ: download the source of openjdk and check it out

Comment: Re, "proper synchronization could be tricky".  Not just tricky, impossible!  The name `isAlive()` is misleading:  If you call `t.isAlive()` and it returns true, that does _not_ mean that thread `t` is alive.  It means that the thread _was_ alive at some instant before or during the `isAlive()` method call, but it does not guarantee that the thread will _still be_ alive by the time your caller takes some action based on the return value.

Comment: @jameslarge - I forgot about that misleading name / semantic.  Clearly, there is a race between the (hypothetical) variable being set and the thread actually starting.  Doing isAlive in native code probably allows them to avoid that.